# Selecting items from a sequence with a minimum difference

Tags: sql, sqlite, select

Let's say we have a table like this:

```
id | num
---+----
 1 | 1
 2 | 3
 3 | 5
 4 | 6
 5 | 7
 6 | 8
```

What I need to do is select all rows such that, when viewed as a sequence, the minimum difference between one row in the result and the next one is at least 3. The desired result should be this:

```
id | num
---+----
 1 | 1
 3 | 5
 6 | 8
```

This is trivial in imperative language:

```
result = [table[0]]
for row in table:
    if row['num'] >= result[-1]['num'] + 3:
        result.append(row)
```

But I'm struggling to find a solution in pure SQL (I'm using SQLite, btw).

I did find a way which looked like this:

```
WITH RECURSIVE
  seq(t) as (
    SELECT 1
    UNION
    SELECT min(num) FROM table, seq WHERE num >= t + 3 AND num < 10
  )
SELECT t FROM seq;
```

But this only worked in a specific version of SQLite, with a later version giving the error that aggregate functions ("min" in this case) aren't allowed in recursive queries.

What I thought would work is this:

```
WITH RECURSIVE
  seq(t) as (
    SELECT 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT num FROM table, seq WHERE num >= t + 3 LIMIT 1
  )
SELECT t FROM seq;
```

But in this case, `LIMIT 1` is applied to the whole subquery, not just the second `SELECT`, so that in the end, `seq` only has one row.

Can this be done?

Comment: can you explain what mean `when viewed as a sequence, the minimum distance between each two neighbors is at least 3`  What is a sequence? What is a neighbors?

Comment: "Sequence" just means that rows have an order, they are sorted by increasing value in `num`. And `neighbours` are two rows next to each other, like row 1 and 2, or 5 and 6. Basically, to get the result, you take the first row and put it into the result. Then you find the row with the lowest `num` where `num` is at least 3 greater than in the first row. That's the second row of the result. And so on.

Comment: There are sequences with multiple possible solutions (e.g., `1,4,5,8`). What should happen?

Comment: Sorry I just dont understand that sequence enought to help you. Good luck.

Comment: @CL The result should be `1, 4, 8`, since `4-1>=3`. After picking `4`, the next valid number has to be at least 7, so we skip the `5` and choose the `8`.